# How to delete entire row if values in a column are NaN

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-cleaning, data

I'd like to drop all the rows containing a NaN values pertaining to a column. Lets assume I have a dataset like this:

```
Age  Height  Weight  Gender
12    5'7     NaN     M
NaN   5'8     160     M
32    5'5     165     NaN
21    NaN     155     F
55    5'10    170     NaN
```

I want to remove all the rows where 'Gender' has NaN values. The output i'd like:

```
Age  Height  Weight Gender
12   5'7     NaN     M
NaN  5'8     160     M
21   NaN     155     F
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really have to tell us what data structure it is in. E.g. is it SQL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well if the dataset is not too large I would suggest using pandas to clean the data. So you would need to first do

**Python2**

```
python2 -m pip install pandas
```

**Python3**

```
python3 -m pip install pandas
```

If you already have anaconda installed you can skip the above step. Next you could go through an IDE (like jupyter) or through the shell type the following commands

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename", dtype=str)
#or if excel file
#df = pd.read_excel("filename", dtype=str)

df = df[pd.notnull(df['Gender'])]
```

Then you would want to save your result in a file with

```
df.to_csv("newfile");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are working on Python Dataframe, Please try this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = df[np.isfinite(df['Gender'])]
```

Or you can use notnull instead of isfinite.

```
import pandas as pd
df = df[pd.notnull(df['Gender'])]
```